# Converting simple list to Numpy arr with correct shape

Tags: python, string, numpy, reshape

I am converting a list of lists (of text strings) into an array, however constantly finding myself 1) printing the shape and then 2) manually doing np.reshape to 'transform' the array so that the data comes down row wise, rather than an endless stream of columns.

Is there anyway I can create the arrays with the correct transformation initially, to avoid having to manually reshape everytime?

E.g. I have a 2d list as follows:

```
a = [['foo', 'bar', 'baz', 'qux']]
```

I convert to an array using:

```
b = np.array(a)
```

It's shape when using b.shape is: `(4,)`

However I need it to be `(4,1) (and use b = b.reshape(4,1))` to look like this:

```
a = [['foo'],
['bar'],
['baz'],
['qux']]
```

**How do I create the array so that originally it becomes (4,1) rather than using the manual reshape?**

Comment: shape of array is (4, 1)

Comment: `shape` represents the number of items in the axes.

Comment: edited thanks...any idea on how to solve the issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your list of lists does create a (4,1) array.  So what was the issue?

```
In [41]: a = [['foo'],
    ...: ['bar'],
    ...: ['baz'],
    ...: ['qux']]
In [42]: arr = np.array(a)
In [43]: arr
Out[43]: 
array([['foo'],
       ['bar'],
       ['baz'],
       ['qux']], dtype='<U3')
In [44]: arr.shape
Out[44]: (4, 1)
```

If you  start with a flat list, you will need to reshape:

```
In [45]: b= arr.ravel().tolist()
In [46]: b
Out[46]: ['foo', 'bar', 'baz', 'qux']
In [47]: np.array(b)
Out[47]: array(['foo', 'bar', 'baz', 'qux'], dtype='<U3')
In [48]: np.array(b).reshape(-1,1)
Out[48]: 
array([['foo'],
       ['bar'],
       ['baz'],
       ['qux']], dtype='<U3')
```

`reshape` (and `ravel`) is trivial in `numpy`.  That's why I created `b` from `arr` rather than edit the original `a` list.

`numpy` array `shape` closely reflects the nesting of lists/[].

If you do get a 1d shape when you expect 2d, check the `dtype`, and pay attention to any 'ragged array' warnings:

```
In [50]: a = [['foo'],
    ...: ['bar'],
    ...: ['baz'],
    ...: ['qux','extra']]
In [51]: np.array(a)
<ipython-input-51-103c848ebb38>:1: VisibleDeprecationWarning: Creating an ndarray from ragged nested sequences (which is a list-or-tuple of lists-or-tuples-or ndarrays with different lengths or shapes) is deprecated. If you meant to do this, you must specify 'dtype=object' when creating the ndarray.
  np.array(a)
Out[51]: 
array([list(['foo']), list(['bar']), list(['baz']),
       list(['qux', 'extra'])], dtype=object)
In [52]: _.shape
Out[52]: (4,)
```

### edit

If you have a list that contains **one** list, you will get a (1,n) array.  That should be obvious.  It's just following the nesting of the lists:

```
In [53]: a = [['foo', 'bar', 'baz', 'qux']]
In [54]: arr = np.array(a)
In [55]: arr
Out[55]: array([['foo', 'bar', 'baz', 'qux']], dtype='<U3')
In [56]: arr.shape
Out[56]: (1, 4)
In [57]: arr.T
Out[57]: 
array([['foo'],
       ['bar'],
       ['baz'],
       ['qux']], dtype='<U3')
```

it reshapes to (4,1) just as easily:

```
In [58]: np.array(a).reshape(-1,1)
Out[58]: 
array([['foo'],
       ['bar'],
       ['baz'],
       ['qux']], dtype='<U3')
```

Comment: apologies you're right the original array is (4,1), I have edited the post now and shown the exact original array which is (4,)

Comment: Yes exactly! That's what happens, I convert my list to an array, it becomes (1,4) but I want it to work in the other orientation to (4,1)...right now I first check shape, then do arr.reshape...but is there not a way to do this at the stage of converting to an array?

Comment: You could do the reshape without checking.  Even if there was a way to make the (n,1) by default, it would just be hiding the reshape in a function.  Look for example at the code for `np.atleast_2d`.  In `numpy` the leading dimension is outermost., and the preferred expansion dimension.

Comment: ok thanks, the problem is I can't do the reshape without checking as I'm doing it for several text files --> lists ---> arrays and want to automate the function to put into a class to be used on other files...also the list I gave as an example is only one list but it has a list of many lists inside.

Comment: This worked perfectly: np.array(a).reshape(-1,1) and prevents me from having to manually check every time, thanks for the solution it is exactly what I needed to automate the process in a class!